# How/why do we use operator.abs

Tags: python, operators, absolute-value

In `operators` module we have a helper method `operator.abs`.  But in python `abs` is already a function, and the only way I know to invoke the `__abs__` method on an object is by function call anyway.

Is there some other fancy way I don't know about to take the absolute value of a number?  If not, why does `operator.abs` exist in the first place, and what is an example where you would have to use it instead of plain old `abs`?

Comment: Simple answers: Not really, probably for the sake of continuity if you have otherwise used `operator` functions, not applicable.

Comment: Consistency; all `__special__` functions have equivalent `special` function aliases.

Comment: No they don't.  This is inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

> **abs**(...)
>       abs(a) -- Same as abs(a).

No, I don’t think there’s some other fancy way you don’t know about, or really any reason at all for this to be here at all except for consistency (since `operator` has methods for the other `__operator__`s).

Comment: But by that logic we should have, say, `operator.__hex__` and many others too.  This seems to be the _only_ one in there which is already a function.

Comment: @wim: Is a method called `__hex__` used by `hex()`?

Comment: @wim: It uses `__index__` in Python 3, and `operator.index` exists.

Comment: @wim: touche, there is a `__hex__` method. Then file an issue and ask why `hex` is not added but `abs` is. They'll tell you it is gone in Python 3 however.

Comment: Well, there are many examples I could pick..  `__hash__` is another one you always get but there's no `operator.hash`

Comment: @wim: Touché indeed! My next best guess would be that absolute value is a (common) mathematical operator, but hashing isn’t – it’s pretty much strictly a computer thing.

Comment: Was there ever in very early python some now-deprecated operator for `abs(x)`, like `|x|` say?

Comment: @wim: I don't think so, and anyway the `operator` module was introduced in 1.5, while the `abs` builtin function already existed before that.

Comment: The [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7255af1a1c50/Lib/operator.py) is bizarre.  They do `from bultins import abs as _abs` and then they do `def abs(a): return _abs(a)` ... ok then ...

Comment: @wim: That’s to be able to have a docstring.