# How is it possible to evaluate +5 in Python?

Tags: python, operators, addition

How does evaluating `+ 5` work (spoiler alert: result is 5)?

Isn't the `+` working by calling the `__add__` method on something? 5 would be "`other`" in:

```
>>> other = 5
>>> x = 1
>>> x.__add__(other)
6
```

So what is the "void" that allows adding 5?

`void.__add__(5)`

Another clue is that:

```
/ 5
```

throws the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: The latter `TypeError` has to do with IPython auto-parentheses feature, it substitutes `/whatever` with `whatever()`. Python has no unary `/` operator.

Comment: @bereal Any link to this feature? It is more than just auto-parenthesis: `/sum (1 2 3 4 5)` returns 15.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary described [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#automatic-parentheses-and-quotes), (same as IPython's `?`-help). Apparently, it's a bit more advanced, than described, for example, `/'abc'` returns `'abc'`, I have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `+` in this case calls the unary magic method [`__pos__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__pos__) rather than [`__add__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__):

```
>>> class A(int):
    def __pos__(self):
        print '__pos__ called'
        return self
...
>>> a = A(5)
>>> +a
__pos__ called
5
>>> +++a
__pos__ called
__pos__ called
__pos__ called
5
```

Python only supports 4(unary arithmetic operations) of them `__neg__`, `__pos__`, `__abs__`, and `__invert__`, hence the `SyntaxError` with `/`. Note that `__abs__` works with a built-in function called [`abs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs), i.e no operator for this unary operation.

---

Note that `/5` (`/` followed by something)is interpreted differently by IPython shell only, for normal shell it is a syntax error as expected:

```
Ashwinis-MacBook-Pro:py ashwini$ ipy
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
>>> /5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-1-2b14d13c234b>", line 1, in <module>
    5()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

>>> /float 1
1.0
>>> /sum (1 2 3 4 5)
15
```

---

```
Ashwinis-MacBook-Pro:~ ashwini$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> /5
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    /5
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> /float 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    /float 1
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Not sure why you include `__abs__` along with the other 3

Comment: @wim `__abs__` has no unary operator but it is still considered an unary operation.

Comment: I don't think you're correct on that - the [docs define](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) clearly a `u_expr` and mention only minus, plus, and invert operations.  Why would you call `int.__abs__` a unary operation but not, say, `int.__nonzero__` or others??

Comment: @wim From Data model page(below [object.__invert__](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__invert__)): *Called to implement the unary arithmetic operations (`-`, `+`, `abs()` and `~`)*.

Comment: Well, there it is!  Bizarre.  Why they call it an "operation" when there is no operator makes no sense for me.  And they even explicitly then give a function call along with the 3 operators ..  *shrugs*

Comment: [As far as I could tell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22387166/674039) there was never an operator for abs in python, and yet there is the apparently useless `operator.abs` also in existence.  Maybe there were once plans to add a syntax for it, and they got shelved.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you've found one of the three [unary operators](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations):

- The unary plus operation `+x` calls the **__pos__()** method.
- The unary negation operation `-x` calls the **__neg__()** method.
- The unary not (or invert) operation `~x` calls the **__invert__()** method.

Answer (score 6):

Per the [language reference on numeric literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#numeric-literals):

> Note that numeric literals do not include a sign; a phrase like `-1`
>   is actually an expression composed of the unary operator `-` and the
>   literal `1`.

And the [section on unary operators](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations):

> The unary `-` (minus) operator yields the negation of its numeric
>   argument.
>
> The unary `+` (plus) operator yields its numeric argument unchanged.

There is no unary `/` (divide) operator, hence the error.

The related *"magic methods"* (`__pos__`, `__neg__`) are covered in [the data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__neg__).

Comment: I see... the explanation now made me evaluate `--+++-1` which is then logically working.

Comment: @PascalvKooten yes, you can chain them arbitrarily

Comment: Note that `/` is actually a `SyntaxError`, it's the IPython shell that does something funky with `/`.