# Why use the functions in the operator module?

Tags: python, operators

What is the point of python's `operator` module? There are many obviously redundant functions there and I don't understand why should one prefer to use these functions rather than other ways to do the same thing.

For example:

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.truth(0)
False
>>> bool(0)
False
```

seem to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/22387166/674039

Answer (score 9):

Its sometimes useful to be able to access the functionality of an operator but as a function. For example to add two numbers together you could do.

```
>> print(1 + 2)
3
```

You could also do

```
>> import operator
>> print(operator.add(1, 2))
3
```

A use case for the function approach could be you need to write a calculator function which returns an answer given a simple formula.

```
import operator as _operator

operator_mapping = {
    '+': _operator.add,
    '-': _operator.sub,
    '*': _operator.mul,
    '/': _operator.truediv,
}

def calculate(formula):
    x, operator, y = formula.split(' ')

    # Convert x and y to floats so we can perform mathematical
    # operations on them.
    x, y = map(float, (x, y))

    return operator_mapping[operator](x, y)

print(calculate('1 + 2'))  # prints 3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

For completeness and consistency. Because having all operators in one place lets you do dynamic lookups later on:

```
getattr(operator, opname)(*arguments)
```

Omitting some operations because they are redundant would defeat that purpose. And because Python names are just references, it is cheap and easy to add a name to the `operator` module that is simply another reference.

Comment: Not very convincing answer for me, because different operations take different numbers of arguments.

Comment: @wim: I did pass in arguments dynamically here. You can trivially group string operators into groups by the number of operators they take too.

Comment: Don't really understand the use-case and seems to violate "one obvious way to do it".  Are you aware of any project on github where the code actually used dynamic lookups on operator module like this?

Comment: @wim: we could slog through [these results](https://searchcode.com/?q=getattr%28operator&loc=0&loc2=10000&lan=19). I can't narrow it down to an exact match, but I see `pandas` uses `getattr(operator, ...)` in their tests.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What do you mean by doing dynamic lookups? Can you write an example?

Comment: @student: I already did in the answer; given `arguments = [42]`, setting `opname = 'truth'` will give you a different result from `opname = 'neg'`, which is different again from `opname = 'index'`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the existence of [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool), it's hard to think of any use-case for `operator.truth` these days. Note that `bool` was new in 2.2.1, and operator predates that, so it may only exist now for historical reasons. There are also other useless functions in the operator module, [such as `operator.abs`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22387166/674039), which simply calls the built-in `abs`.

Not everything in `operator` is entirely useless, though - operator's [C implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_operator.c), if available, can offer performance gains over pure Python implementations. The `itemgetter`, `attrgetter` and `methodcaller` functions are more readable and generally better performing utility functions for tasks which are often handled by lambda functions.